# MySQL If Left Outter join exists

Tags: mysql

I have a query like so:

```
 SELECT process.id, name, item, file, sort, userprocess.id 
 FROM `process` 
 left outer join userprocess ON userprocess.processid = process.id 
 WHERE userprocess.userid = 11
```

What I am trying to do is add an extra column that is a bool and if userprocess.id is not null have it as true, if null have it false for userid 11...what is the best way to do this?

I have two rows in process and one in userprocess, but this query only returns 1 row. I am expecting it to return 2 rows, one as true and the other as false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move your `WHERE` condition into the `ON` condition as it is removing any rows where `userprocess.id` might be `NULL` (as in that case `userprocess.userid` will also be `NULL` and so the `WHERE` test will fail). Then you can add a boolean column to your output based on `userprocess.id` being NULL or not:

```
 SELECT process.id, name, item, file, sort, userprocess.id, 
        userprocess.id IS NOT NULL AS userprocess_exists
 FROM `process` 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN userprocess ON userprocess.processid = process.id
                            AND userprocess.userid = 11
```